# Android Page Adapter issue : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.setLayerType

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I am using pagerAdapter to display the contents with Fragment support.  I am  getting the error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.setLayerType

when I run the application on Android 2.2 or below.  But on the devices with Android 4.0 this is working fine. Please check the Log details with the error :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.setLayerType
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> com.dealdetails.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:415)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:160)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:895)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:380)
>
> 02-28 11:19:08.205: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27823):     at
> my_package.main_View_Pager(my_java_class.java:1214)

Please suggest how I can run the App without error on devices with OS level < 2.2

Thanks in Advance

Tim.

Comment: What does your code look like, specifically at line 415 on MyFragment.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please suggest how I can run the App without error on devices with OS
>   level < 2.2

Don't use that method on versions below `Honeycomb`(API level 11) because it doesn't exist, it was introduced starting from `Honeycomb` and you can see this by checking the [documentation for the `WebView` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).
I don't know how you could get around this for lower API versions.

Comment: Ok.. So no backward compatibility for webview?

Comment: @Timson Unfortunately no. You either write your code to only use that method on versions starting with Honeycomb or you try to backport the method(which will be hard to do(if it can be done)) on the lower versions.